# File_x exists in gCloud directory, but gcloud deploy gives FileNotFoundError for File_x

Tags: flask, web-deployment, gcloud

I've successfully tested my `Flask` app in my local machine, and I've set up the correct `app.yaml` and `requirements.txt` files (and the rest of the application files) for `gCloud`, and yet I get a `FileNotFoundError` for a file that actually exists in the directory I created in `gCloud` Shell.

For context, I'm very new to the `Flask` app and `gCloud` app deployment.

I've successfully tested my `Flask` app in my local machine, and I've set up the correct `app.yaml` and `requirements.txt` files, and the rest of my files, in `gCloud` cloud shell. For context, within my main project directory (named `FlaskProject_App`), there exists a subfolder "static" with the file `CEW_file.txt`.

However, when I deploy the project, I reach an error: 
with open(`CEW_file.txt`) as word_file:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'CEW_file.txt'

I tried listing the entire path (in gCloud) of `CEW_file.txt` in the open() function, yet it still gave the same error - that it could not find the file. The path I tried in the open() function was `/home/vmagent/app/static/CEW_file.txt` but that did not work either.

I also tried `~/FlaskProject_App/static/CEW_file.txt` since those directories are listed in my `gCloud` (as below in the picture), but this also failed, giving the same `FileNotFoundError`.

```
common_words = []
with open('~/FlaskProject_App/static/CEW_file.txt', 'r') as 
word_file:
f = word_file.read()
for line in f.split('\n'):
    common_words.append(line)
```

I expected the gcloud app deploy command to work, but instead, even though my file system in gCloud has the `CEW_file.txt` stored as:
`[myusername]/FlaskProject_app/static/CEW_file.txt`, the open() command still gave the `FileNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is just telling you that the file cannot be found in the path that you are providing.

I understand that your code is in the `FlaskProject_app` folder and inside it you have another one called `static` which contains the `CEW_file.txt`.

If that is the case then you should be able to open the file using

```
open('static/CEW_file.txt', 'r')
```

If that doesn't work try using these lines to see which files are in the `static` folder:

```
cdir = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(cdir+"/static")
```

and print the files variable to see if you can find `CEW_file.txt` in the list. If you cannot see it there, then you will have to move the file there and that should solve your issue.

Comment: Hi @mgoya! I wanted to ask - those are commands (referring to the os commands) I should be typing into the python shell, or the gcloud shell?

I don't think it would make sense to use those commands on my local machine's python, since I know where that CEW.txt file is on my local machine.

Comment: nevermind - i just opened the python application through the google cloud shell and am writing the os commands there

Comment: so i wrote the files = os.listdir(cdir+"/static") command and actually google cloud shell gave me an error saying that there's no such path :O should I keep CEW_file.txt where it is then?

Comment: Can you run the command `find . -name "CEW_file.txt"` in your cloud shell? that command will show you the exact route of the file.